# Openid Server store trusted sites with identity

Tags: php, openid, janrain

I have just started use janrain openid for php ( [link](http://janrain.com/openid-enabled/) ).
Once I had created another table with columns like id, nick, email and an user I'd like to remember which sites I trusted.
Janrain creates 2 tables oid_nonces and oid_associations.
I haven't understood what's their work, if they can be useful, I know only that it seems that the oid_nonces is unused.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OpenID an associations is a shared secret between the relying party (you) and the OpenID provider. This shared secret is used when the user, after logging in with is OpenID provider, returns to your site. At that time, the OpenID provider has added a signature in the URL parameter `openid.sig`. You verify this signature with the shared secret associated with the OpenID provider.

The OpenID nonce is a one time token that is used to prevent reuse of a return URL. The first time a user comes to your site with a unkown `openid.nonce` your server will do the OpenID processing normally. If somebody then comes to your site with the same `openid.nonce` it would be a sign that somebody is trying to reuse your user’s identity.

Comment: what does "trying to reuse" mean? When I log in, no query affects oid_nonces